# How to send data across domain using javascript and tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, tampermonkey

I follow a forum where people post many links. I've made a script, using javascript and tampermonkey (chrome extension), that first opens all unread thread in new tabs, than it looks for unread posts that have links and opens those links in new tabs.

This script saves me a lot of time and it is working pretty well. Nevertheless, I would like to improve it.

I want to change the title of the page that has been just opened in order for it to show the name of the thread on which the link that sent to this page was. For example:

On the thread "Fruits" there is a link that opens a new tab to a website "www.apple.com". I would like to change the tittle of this page to "Fruits - The name of the page", so I can know from which thread this link comes.

I use localstorage and sessionstorage to send information from one page to another page when my script is navigating inside the forum domain, but I have no idea what I can use to send information across different domains.

Furthermore, I would like to know if there is a way to tell tampermonkey to run the script according to the link that was opened.

I do know how to change the tittle of the page, the problem is taking the name of the thread that is on the forum domain and using it to change the tittle on the new tab that is on a domain different from the forum domain.

Comment: You can use `document.title = "abc"` to set `title` of `document`

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is not changing the tittle, but passing the name of the thread that is in the forum domain to the new tab that is under another different domain so then I can use it to change the tittle of the page.

Comment: Set the same script to run on all relevant pages. Then you can use `GM_setValue()` and `GM_addValueChangeListener()` to communicate across domains from one script instance to another instance of the same script.

Comment: An easier way that works in most, but not all, cases is to pass extra information in the URL parameters, or in the hash, when you open the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage doesn't allow access on different domain. You need to store that data in database server. The easiest is to sign up a database service, and it provides API you can use. If you're going to host your own, you must write your own scripts that allow CORS to provide the access to database server.